# Why is $G/K$ a space of non-positive curvature, where $G$ is a complex reductive group and $K$ is its maximal compact subgroup

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symmetric-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of Kempf-Ness theorem, which relates polystability (Mumford's definition) and zeroes of moment maps. A key part of this proof is the following idea, that for a complex reductive group $G$ (By Weyl's result, this is the complexification of a compact lie group $K$), $G/K$ is geodesically complete and its geodesics are of the form $[e^{it\eta} g]$ where $\eta \in \mathfrak{k}$ and $g \in G$, essentially one parameter subgroups.

Why is this true? I do know that $K$ is compact and hence it has a bi-invariant metric coming from the Killing form. Can I somehow extend this metric to $G$ and get a bi-invariant metric on $G$? I do know that for bi-invariant metrics, one will have the connection given by $[X,Y]$ and this would give rise to the required geodesics. Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell the link between the question and the "negatively curved" part of the title. With $G = SU(n+1)$ and $K=S(U(n)\times U(1))$, isn't $G$ a complex reductive group (I don't know much about this theory)? Note that $G/K \simeq \Bbb C P^n$ is not negatively curved since its bi-invariant metric is the Fubini-Study metric which has positive curvature

Comment: @Didier Firstly I apologize for the typo. It should have been non-positively curved. Secondly, why is the complexification of $K$, $G$? Also $K$ needs to be maximal compact. I do not think the $K$ you mention will be maximal compact

Comment: You can find a proof in Helgason's book on symmetric spaces. The assumption that $G$ is complex is irrelevant here.